# Try understand rails through debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm newbie in Rails and want understand how it works. I want go through debugger from HTTP-request from browser to Rails HTTP-response. I run pry-debugger in  Rails::Application#call method where env - parsed HTTP-request.

```
222: def call(env)
223: 
224:   env["ORIGINAL_FULLPATH"] = build_original_fullpath(env)
225: =>   binding.pry
226:   super(env)
227: end`
```

after two steps I go through super(evn) to Rails::Engine#call method (super - Ruby keyword)

```
478: def call(env)
479: =>   app.call(env.merge!(env_config))
480: end`
```

after next step I expect go into app.call method where app is object of class ActionDispatch::Static but I appear in app method of Rails::Engine class

```
467: def app
468:   @app ||= begin
469:     config.middleware = config.middleware.merge_into(default_middleware_stack)
470:     config.middleware.build(endpoint)
471: =>   end
472: end
```

why? what I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to understand rails, try to read "Crafting Rails Applications" book. There is good explanation for many parts of rails app.

Comment: What command are you using? "next" or "step"? What version if ruby are you using?

Comment: Command - step. I'm using ruby 1.9 and rails 3.2.13.

Comment: Can you reproduce this again? pry-debugger should never stop at that line... You might have changed the code but don't reload the debugger.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it many times.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use `debugger` instead of   `binding.pry`? I think you should open an issue in either debugger or pry-debugger depending on the result of this last test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on ruby 2.0 (and this is not expected behaviour) you should try `pry-byebug` instead of `pry-debugger` -- ruby 2.0 changed some debugging API and the `debugger` gem (which pry-debugger relies on) sometimes acts strangely.

Comment: I use ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.13